# C++ template auto return type with arrow-notation require decltype?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

C++11 introduced the arrow-notation(don't know the name) for return types in functions:

```
template <typename T>
auto fun(T&& a) -> decltype(bar(a)){ ... }
```

but according to scott meyer, using auto as the return type by itself will drop all const and reference qualifiers(because it follows the same pattern as template deduction), and therefore the idiomatic way is to do `decltype(auto)` to keep all qualifiers on top of the type.

However, in this context, is `auto` inferred to be `decltype(bar(a))`? Then would `decltype(auto)` be `decltype(decltype(bar(a)))`? Would that be redundant?

Comment: *don't know the name* This is called a trailing return type.

Comment: If you explicitly specify it, it's not inferring anything.

Comment: this `auto` is different than `auto somthing = …`, so it doesn't drop anything. Read Scott Meyer's book again.

Comment: `decltype(auto)` is a special thing with its own meaning, it is not `decltype` applied to the result of `auto` deduction.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you have a [trailing return type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function), the `auto` keyword appears purely as an element of notation. The return type becomes whatever type comes after the `->`. No type deduction is performed. This is simply how function declarations with a trailing return type are written. Auto return type deduction only happens when you do *not* have a trailing return type, i.e., `auto` is used as a placeholder return type with no `-> …` at the end of your function declarator.

Comment: "Auto return type deduction only happens when you do not have a trailing return type, i.e., auto is used as a placeholder return type with no -> … at the end of your function declarator." maybe it's my lacking knowledge of the english language or the many hours i'm awake ... but that sentence doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @Swordfish The answer is clear and minimal. I guess your knowlege(book mabe...) of std C++ is outdated. You may need to get a newer revision of the book. but to put it short, there are 2 auto declared return type syntaxes: auto return type( no -> etc...) and trailing return type. 2nd form is used in order to simplify complex typenames via injected typenames.

Comment: @Red.Wave Are you talking `auto foo() { retur 42; }` vs `auto foo() -> some_type { ...` ?

Comment: @Swordfish yes. That's what kenzel points out. If you need examples ask him to include them.

Comment: @Red.Wave it's ok, I know that syntax. I was just confused by how Michael put it. English is not my first language.

Comment: @Swordfish not mine too. my 2nd language is C++.

Comment: @Red.Wave bragg0r! :p ;)

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `int& bar();` (or using **trailing return type** syntax `auto bar() -> int&;`),

you may declare several functions:

- `int& f1();` or `auto f1() -> int&;`.
- `decltype(bar()) f2();` or `auto f2() -> decltype(bar());`. (return type is `int&`). `decltype` allows SFINAE usage for template function.
- `decltype(auto) f3() { return bar(); }` Definition needed (deduced as `int&`) (No SFINAE).
- `auto f4() { return bar(); }` Definition needed (deduced as `int`) (No SFINAE).

`decltype(expression)` is a **type**, and `decltype(type)` is invalid, so 
`decltype(decltype(expression))` is invalid too.